# FOR loop: what does it mean if I see two initialExpression(s) in FOR loop, js?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

If I see in the FOR loop condition:

```
let i = 0, chr
```

like here:

[image]

from here: [String.prototype.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

what does the second part (`chr`) of initialExpression  mean?

Comment: it is a declaration of `chr`. it looks like it is use inside of the loop for a character.

Comment: It creates a variable `chr`, same as `i`. This is effectively a use of the comma operator, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: It's just declaring two variables. It works the same way outside the loop header.

Comment: ahha I got it tnx

Comment: @CBroe: This is not the comma operator, it's part of the syntax of variable declarations. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var